# Set a mailto link with a subject containing an ampersand (&)

Tags: html, email, tags, mailto

Im using the following `mailto` link to send an email:

```
 <a class="share3" title="" href="mailto:?subject=@check&amp;body=@domain">
```

It works well, but sometimes my subject will contain an ampersand (&) character, and when it does my email is created without a body.

Any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In order to get special/reserved characters into a URL, you must encode them - to get an `&` to work, it must be encoded to `%26`.

More details here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 5):

use `%26` for the & in the subject.